# leetcode compiler doesn't work like eclipse

Tags: java

I tried to solve 
https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/submissions/
using Java

I usually try these things using Eclipse before submit on online.

Here I attached codes in Eclipse

```
public class PrintAnnotationExample{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int index = 0;
    int max =0;
    int temp = 0;
    int[] test = new int[] {-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4};

    while(index<test.length) {
        temp+= test[index];
        if(temp <0) {
            while(index<test.length-1 && test[index]<0) {
                ++index;
            }
            temp = 0;
        }
        max = (max >= temp ) ? max : temp;
        ++index;
    }
    ///
    System.out.println(max);

 }
}
```

It worked! the expected output is 6, and it makes 6 either.

However, 
In Leetcode submission page, It doesn't work

```
class Solution {
public int index = 0;
public int max =0;
public int temp = 0;

public int maxSubArray(int[] nums) {

    while(index<nums.length) {//아직 배열범위 안에 있을경우
        temp+=  nums[index];
        if(temp <0) {
            while(index<nums.length-1 && nums[index]<0) {
                ++index;
            }
            temp = 0;
        }
        max = (max >= temp ) ? max : temp;
        ++index;
    }
    return max;
}
```

}
It shows me 1, not 6...

weird, may be I got something wrong in my head about Java semantics..

Comment: Why `args.length-1`?

Comment: @user7 
Yeap! I edited . Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codes you are executing in Eclipse and Leetcode are clearly different, so you need to focus on the differences between them ... rather than concluding (incorrectly) that there are compiler / language differences.

One of the differences is that in the Eclipse version `index`, `max` and `temp` are local variables.  In the Leetcode version they are instance variables that don't get initialized each time your method is called.  If LeetCode instantiates your class once and calls the method multiple times, this will lead to incorrect behavior.

---

> may be I got something wrong in my head about Java semantics.

Maybe.  Or it could just be a mistake.

But either way, it is inadvisable to use instance variables to hold the state of a method call.  Use local variables for instead:

- Using local variables for this avoids the mistake you made; i.e. forgetting to reinitialize.
- Using instance variables for this makes the method non-reentrant; i.e. concurrent or overlapping calls to the method will interfere with each other.  This will be problematic if the method is called recursively, or if it is called from multiple threads.